# Angular routing with pages following parameters

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-router, routeparams, route-parameters

I have an Angular 5 app in which I need a URL to use the following form:

```
www.example.com/#/company/<companyId>/transactions
```

I am using a non-named router outlet `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

The companyId is a parameter. Initially I left off the transactions portion in the router and verified that I can correctly reach the transactions page associated with the CompanyTransactionsComponent.

The router rule was:

```
www.example.com/#/company/<id>/
{ path: 'company/:companyId', component: CompanyTransactionsComponent }
this.router.navigateByUrl('/company/' + user.companyId);
```

which worked fine, but when I changed to add /transactions:

```
www.example.com/#/company/<id>/transactions/
{ path: 'company/:companyId/transactions', component: CompanyTransactionsComponent }
this.router.navigateByUrl('/company/' + user.companyId + '/transactions/');
```

This was giving me an error `Cannot match any routes.` so I tried a couple other options below:

```
{ 
    path: 'company/:companyId', 
    component: CompanyTransactionsComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'transactions',
            component: CompanyTransactionsComponent
        }
    ]
},
```

and:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'company/:companyId', component: CompanyTransactionsComponent }
],
RouterModule.forChild([
    { 
        path: 'company/:companyId',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'transactions',
                component: CompanyTransactionsComponent
            }
        ]
    },
])
```

Both give the same error. This seems to only happen because I use the /transactions after the parameter /:companyId. Any idea how I can accomplish having a sub-page following the parameter in the url?

*EDIT*
CompanyTransactionsComponent is used for both parent and child because there is not yet a CompanyHomeComponent, so the transactions page will be the default page when no sub-page is entered. There are multiple children besides the CompanyTransactionsComponent I left out to keep the code shorter.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the "sub-page" if you are routing to the same component?

This code will allow you to have a route with the additional text in the URL. But if you are indeed looking to have a "sub-page", it should route to a different component to display that "sub-page".

```
{ 
    path: 'company/:companyId', 
    component: CompanyTransactionsComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'transactions',
            component: CompanyTransactionsComponent  //<-- This should be the "sub page"
        }
    ]
},
```

Also, when defining the `children` property as you have above, you normally add a second `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the "parent" component's template. In this example, it would be the `CompanyTransactionsComponent` template.

If you don't really need to display another route, then this should do it:

```
{ 
    path: 'company/:companyId/transactions', 
    component: CompanyTransactionsComponent,
},
```

Comment: We will later add, say, a CompanyHomeComponent which will be the parent. There are multiple children I left out for simplicity's sake. The last code you listed is the first thing I tried, which led me to try using the children attribute.

Comment: That last syntax *should* work. Have you tried `this.router.navigate(['/company', user.companyId, 'transactions']);` instead of navigateByUrl?

Comment: That does seem to work, so I hadn't tried refreshing the page, which would have worked all along. But I find it strange that `this.router.navigateByUrl('/company/' + user.companyId + '/transactions/');` does not work

Comment: Actually, refreshing the page does not work - I really thought it did, but as I'm trying it now it always gives me the same error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'company/<id>'` - It is missing the /transactions in the URL for some reason. I also realized that my example URLs I provided were missing the hash `/#/`, so I edited the question to add that in

Comment: Can you build a simple stackblitz that demonstrates your error with the minimum amount of code?

Answer (score 0):

`transactions` as child route should work. As the path match is always remainder of the url.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'company/:companyId',
    component: CompanyTransactionsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'transactions',
        component: CompanyTransactionsComponent
      }
    ]
  }];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
      )
      // other imports here
    ],
  })
```